# unable to install SonarQube from eclipse

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint

while installing SonarQube through eclipse market place, giving me some error given below

Will not be installed
1: SonarQube Erlang Configuration helper
2: SonarQube PythonConfiguration helper

thus failing my sonarqube installation.

how to get rid of this problem ?

Comment: This plugin is deprecated. You should use [SonarLint](http://www.sonarlint.org/) (version 2 will be more configurable).

Answer (score 0):

Don't choose to install Erlang connector if you don't work on an Erlang project (using ErlIDE).